# Why can I write to a folder but DirectorySecurity.GetAccessRules doesn't have any rules for my user

Tags: c#

I'm writing a tool that checks that a user has permissions to read, write and delete files in a  given set of folders.

I know that my user can do all these actions in these folders using windows explorer as I have tried it manually and my program is running as me.

When I call

```
AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = Directory.GetAccessControl(somePath).GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
```

The list of rules, is for groups that I am definitely not part of. In fact they are on another domain (apart from BUILTIN\Administrators, which I'm not in).

When I use windows explorer to check my effective access on the folder (right click -> properties -> security -> advanced -> effective access) it says that I don't have any access at all. Which is strange as I can definitely create new files in the folder.

I've included my code below:

```
private static void CheckPermissions(string path, FileSystemRights desiredRights)
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = Directory.GetAccessControl(row.Path).GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

            FileSystemRights allAllowRights = 0;
            FileSystemRights allDenyRights = 0;

            foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
            {
                if (identity.Groups.Contains(rule.IdentityReference) || identity.Owner.Equals(rule.IdentityReference) || rule.IdentityReference.ToString() == identity.User.Value) 
                {
                    if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                    {
                        allDenyRights |= rule.FileSystemRights;
                    }
                    else if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
                    {
                        allAllowRights |= rule.FileSystemRights;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (allDenyRights.HasFlag(desiredRights)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"FAILURE, User {identity.Name} is explicitly DENIED a required permission on, {path}");
            }

            if (!allAllowRights.HasFlag(desiredRights)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"FAILURE, User {identity.Name} missing required ALLOW permission on, {path}");
            }

        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"FAILURE, User {identity.Name} does not have any access to {path}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"FAILURE, User {identity.Name} something went wrong while checking permissions {path}");
        }
    }
```